# Как хранятся в памяти многомерные массивы?

Tags: c++, массивы, память, хранение-данных

Раньше я думал, что когда мы создаем многомерный массив, например

```
int arr[2][3] = 
{
    {1, 2, 3},
    {1, 2, 3}
}
```

в памяти выделяется две ячейки, каждая из которых занимает `sizeof(int) * 3` и таким образом можно легко обращаться к любому элементу. Например при обращении к последней тройке `arr[1][2]`, на уровне указателей это будет выглядеть так `*(arr + (sizeof(int) * 3 * 1) + 2)`. Ну и памяти занимает такой массив ровно 2х3.

Но затем я увидел такую формулу на уровне указателей `arr[1][2] => *(*(arr + 1) + 2)` и пришел к выводу, что многомерный массив хранится в памяти следующим образом (здесь я буду обозначать память вот так `0[5]`, где `0` - адрес ячейки, `[5]` - значение, которое хранится внутри ячейки): `0[адрес 2], 1[адрес 5], 2[1], 3[2], 4[3], 5[1], 6[2], 7[3]`. И при таком хранении можно легко понять почему в этой формуле `*(*(*(arr + i) + j) + k)` на каждом уровне идет разыменование. Однако при таком способе хранения тот же массив уже занимает 2 + 2x3.

Так как хранятся многомерные массивы и если описанный мной второй способ верный, то в чем его преимущество над первым?

Comment: *Объект типа массива содержит последовательно размещенное в памяти непустое множество из N подобъектов типа T.* (c) Стандарт. Так что двумерный массив, например — просто массив *последовательно размещенных в памяти* одномерных массивов, каждый из которых — последовательно размещенные в памяти элементы...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Нет, для массива в памяти хранятся только его элементы, и никаких указателей. `int arr[2][3]` занимает только `sizeof(int) * 2 * 3` байт места.

Но, одновременно с этим, формула `arr[1][2] => *(*(arr + 1) + 2)` - правильная.

Фокус в том, что нужные указатели вычисляются на лету. Во многих ситуациях массивы автоматически преобразуются в указатель на свой первый элемент, в том числе в этом примере. Получающиеся указатели вычисляются на ходу, и не хранятся постоянно в памяти.

Еще, нужно понимать, что многомерные массивы - это просто обычные (одномерные) массивы, но у которых тип элемента - тоже массив. Для них нет каких-то специальных правил.

Рассмотрим `*(*(arr + i) + j)`.

- `+` сначала преобразует массив `arr` (типа `int[2][3]`) в указатель на его первый элемент (как если бы вы сделали `&arr[0]`), типа `int (*)[3]` ("указатель на массив из 3 int-ов").
- Затем `+ i` сдвигает указатель на `i * sizeof(тип-элемента)` байт, где тип элемента - `int[3]`, а `sizeof(int[3]) == sizeof(int) * 3`.
- Затем `*` разыменовывает указатель, и результат имеет тип `int[3]` (массив из 3 int-ов).
- Дальше все то же самое повторяется для второго индекса. `+` превращает массив в указатель типа `int *`, и т.д.

---

> в памяти выделяется две ячейки, каждая из которых занимает `sizeof(int) * 3`

Я надеюсь вы понимаете, что элементы массива идут в памяти подряд, поэтому вместо "две ячейки по `sizeof(int)*3`" можно было бы с тем же успехом сказать "6 ячеек по `sizeof(int)`". Это просто 6 int-ов подряд.

Comment: И все же в ячейке по адресу `(arr + i)` будет хранится не само число, а указатель на первый элемент "подмассива", верно? И насколько я понял сами "подмассивы" могут рассполагаться в памяти не в упорядоченом виде. И да, я понимаю, что ячейки рассположены последовательно; **"в памяти выделяется две ячейки, каждая из которых занимает `sizeof(int) * 3`"** здесь я и имел ввиду, что последовательно идет 6 ячеек, но они сгруппированы так, что первый индекс i в `arr[i][j]` имеет шаг размером в 3 int-овых ячейки. Хочу получить ответ почему этот способ не используется.

Comment: @helloworld *"будет хранится не само число, а указатель на первый элемент "подмассива""* Неверно, там хранится число. (Или, правильнее сказать, массив из трех чисел. Хотя адрес подмассива и его первого элемента совпадает, все-таки тип указателя `arr + i` - это `int (*)[3]`, а не `int *`, поэтому правильнее говорить, что он указывает на весь подмассив целиком, а не на его первый элемент, хотя, повторюсь, адреса и того и другого одинаковые.) *"почему этот способ не используется"* Какой, второй? Казалось бы, зачем тратить лишнее место в памяти на кучу указателей?

Comment: Такое чуство, что вы не прочитали ответ, или почему-то не поняли. Я же говорю, `*(arr + i)` - это не указатель, а (под)массив из трех интов. Он кажется вам указателем потому, что `+` преобразует его в указатель, но результат преобразования вычисляется на ходу (а не хранится заранее рядом с элементами массива).